# libgpsd.so: undefined reference to `bachk'

Tags: linux, gcc, centos, gpsd

When trying to build gpsd from source on CentOs 5, I get this error:

```
    ./libgpsd.so: undefined reference to 'bachk'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What in the world is bachk´?

Comment: Looks like once again CentOs has an old version of a lib, this time the bluez-lib-devel...

Answer (score 2):

Looks like once again CentOs has an old version of a lib, this time the bluez-lib-devel..